# Swift: How to determine which control was clicked on mouseDown

Tags: swift, cocoa, mouseevent, appkit

I am trying to catch mouse down events on some of my controls in the (Cocoa with Storyboards) application window.

If I override `mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)` in my `ViewController` class, I face two issues:

1. It is not possible to identify (directly) which exactly control in the window has been clicked. To do so, I use the following:

**Swift 4:**

```swift
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        let point: NSPoint = event.locationInWindow
        let view: NSView = self.view.hitTest(point)!
        if type(of:view) == NSTextField.self // with tags is also fine
        {
            // do something with the control (in the example NSTextField)
            // (view as! NSTextField).backgroundColor = NSColor.systemPink
        }
    }
```

I am a little bit puzzled, why for such a basic GUI operation, there isn't a "native" event handler, as provided for the mouse click (by creating an `@IBAction`).
Am I missing something, or this is the way to catch and handle the mouse down events?

2. For some controls, e.g. `NSLevelIndicator`, my overridden method is not called. Why?

Comment: Is the control a subclass of `NSControl`? Does the control handle the mouseDown event?

Comment: Yes, I tried with controls derived from `NSCotrol`, e.g. `NSTextField`, `NSLevelIndicator`. However, I was not able to define a `mouseDown` handler for one or group of controls (in which case I would expect to have some way to distinguish for which object this handler has been called).
I am not sure what you mean with the second question.

Comment: Take a look at `NSClickGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Keith is correct. It's for NSView and not NSViewController. Although Apple shows mouseDown works for both, but in some complex setup it gives bugs which ends up not getting the mouseDown event tracked. What you can do is assign an event tracker and see if the `self` got clicked.

example:

`NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents`

Answer (score -1):

You must override NSView mouseDown, not NSViewController mouseDown.